# Pulse width modulation level shift using an op amp for motor speed control?

Tags: operational-amplifier, motor, pwm

I have a number of DC motors that I'd like to run in the 0v to 3v range via PWM. I have the following circuit,

[image]

The PWM frequency is 490 Hz (out from an Arduino Nano) between 0v and 5v.

What to put in the dashed box is what's puzzling me. I came across the classic inverting amplifier circuit,

[image]

So for me a ratio of `Rf/Rin` of about `0.6` would work, I'm not concerned with phase shift (at least I dont think so).

Is it that straight forward? Am I missing something important here? eg will this buffer the controller from any back EMF in the motors...

Comment: 490Hz is a sound frequency. Do you want everybody nearby to hear the motors buzzing? Quiet motors are fed an ultrasonic frequency higher than 22kHz.

Comment: @Audioguru its the default on most Arduinos, it can be changed though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *What to put in the dashed box is what's puzzling me*

You would normally use a half-bridge MOSFET driver to provide the needed current (at low volt drop) to the motor.

> *I came across the classic inverting amplifier circuit*

No, not a good idea because op-amps either provide too little output current or drop too much voltage when feeding heavier currents for a motor.

> *Am I missing something important here?*

Use a half-bridge MOSFET output chip. You can even use a [full H-bridge](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/TB67H450AFNG_datasheet_en_20201217.pdf?did=70454&prodName=TB67H450AFNG) if you want to reverse the motor direction: -

[image]

In fact, it's probably easier to find full H-bridge chips to do the job. Here's a [chip from TI](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8848.pdf?ts=1673793141733&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FDRV8848%253Futm_source%253Dgoogle%2526utm_medium%253Dcpc%2526utm_campaign%253Dasc-mdbu-null-prodfolderdynamic-cpc-pf-google-wwe_int%2526utm_content%253Dprodfolddynamic%2526ds_k%253DDYNAMIC%2BSEARCH%2BADS%2526DCM%253Dyes%2526gclid%253DCjwKCAiA5Y6eBhAbEiwA_2ZWIVdtajeAxAJQuHGvKuJND9LBQHFSDhW0bUP9F2XgexPbYY7ska23oRoCx8YQAvD_BwE%2526gclsrc%253Daw.ds) that has two half-bridges: -

[image]